# Benifits of content_main.xml in android studio 1.4 & later versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

What is the exact benefits of  content_main.xml in android studio 1.4 & later versions, do we have to make separate content_***.xml files for every layout we make?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anroid Studio auto generates the files from 1.4+**

`content_main.xml` is layout (you can name it anything). It contains the contents of your layout apart from app bar and sliding appbar and fab(floating action bar)

You don't really need it. If you don't  want android studio to auto generate it for you. Try choosing Empty Activity.

Comment: Got It..Actually at star Im bit confused, I think Its same like "App.XAML" in Visual Studio. I think this extra .XML file is not such effective.

Comment: each xml file does something...it depends on how you use it.